# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process 2

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

I have log shipping enabled on my database. I created a file, with let's say `logical name 'AB'` of 50 MB at location `E:\Databases\AB.ndf`. However, I later dropped this file and created another file with `logical name 'AB_File'` of 10 MB at same location `E:\Databases\AB.ndf`. Now the server where the backup was moved to is failing with error:

```
Error: 

1) Could not apply log backup file 'some location of a .trn file' to secondary database

2)The operating system returned the error '32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'E:\Databases\AB.ndf'.

3) File 'AB_File' cannot be restored to 'E:\Databases\AB.ndf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
```

I have tried running the following script:

```
RESTORE LOG [db_name] FROM
DISK =  'E:\Log_Shipping\\db_name_20160817070500.trn'
WITH MOVE 'AB_FILE'
TO 'E:\Databases\AB.ndf',
standby = N'E:\Databases\\db_name_20160818.tuf'
```

I don't seem to be able to fix this. Please help!

The file location on the backup server is the same as that on primary server. Also, the file-group was dropped and the file names are correct.

Answer (score 2):

As you said the error

> The operating system returned the error '32(The process cannot access
>   the file because it is being used by another process.)' while
>   attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation'

The reason for this is that the name of the database files of the databases you are trying to restore already exists.

This could be for two reasons, either you have used the same create scripts for the same database on all instances or you have already done a restore of the database you are trying to restore now to that instance.

**To solve this issue do the following:**

> 2. In the restore page in SSMS, press the "options" tab.
> 3. In the "Restore as" column change the name of the datafile(s) and log file to something unique.

Then hit the restore button and that should be it.

for your ref [Here](http://www.sqlserverf1.com/common-database-restore-errors-in-sql-server/)

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2012 doesn't have the Options tab. Pressing on Tools drop down menu enlists 'Options' below 'customize' and others  but I feel you're trying to tell me something else. Could you please elaborate

Comment: @Ritesh Bhakre, Right Click on that database , which you want to restore. Over there you shall find out 'Options'  there.

Comment: Right-clicking on the said db provides nothing called as 'options' , however there's 'Tasks', clicking on that further providers 'Restore' and further clicking on that provides 2 options: 'Page' and 'Transaction Log'.

Comment: @Ritesh Bhakre,Right click the DB->Properties->Options

Comment: Doing as you said provides drop down options: 'Automatic', 'Containment', 'Cursor', 'Filestream', 'Miscellaneous', 'Recovery', 'Service Broker' and 'State', Recovery option further has 'Page Verify' and 'Target Recovery Time'. I can't use any of these to fix my issue. 
Please help

Comment: You are in the wrong dialog window. The options @MdHaidarAliKhan refers to, are in the Restore dialog, not the Database Properties.

Answer (score 0):

Check few things

1. Logical and physical file name
2. files are still exist in the folder
3. verify file location

Try

```
RESTORE LOG [db_name] FROM
DISK =  'E:\Log_Shipping\\db_name_20160817070500.trn'
WITH FILE=1,
    MOVE 'AB_FILE'
    TO 'E:\Databases\AB.ndf',
    standby  N'E:\Databases\\db_name_20160818.tuf',
    NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE, RECOVERY, 
;
GO
```

Hope it will fix your problem.

Comment: For log shipping, shouldn't this be `NORECOVERY`? Otherwise, I don't think you can apply the next log file.